# How to set-up a Rapsberry Pi workstation for Debianedu/skolelinux services?

Tags: raspbian

Debianedu/Skolelinux is a distribution to manage workstation (with or without a hard disk), thin client (via LTSP) and other stuff of a typical school network.

The most recent instructions I can find are [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/HowTo/RaspberryPiWorkstation).

Raspbian contains some packages for Debianedu: `debian-edu-install`,  `debian-edu-config`, etc.

How should I install them?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) The link you have given explains everything what to do to install *Debianedu/Skolelinux*. So what exactly is your problem? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: I didn't find the scripts but now i have, they're simply in their folder /usr/share/debian-edu-config/tools. I'm a silly boy. However now there is a problem of conflict between python-minimal and python-central. I'm using Raspbian Buster version. I can answer myself to my question.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install debian-edu-config
```

After having installed debian-edu-config and all the dependencies proposed, all the necessary scripts are in their folder:

```
cd /usr/share/debian-edu-config/tools
```

Do the rest indicated in the [link](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/HowTo/RaspberryPiWorkstation)

I couldn't use Rapbian-Buster for a conflict between python-minimal and python-central, so i used strech and it works great!!!

Xfce doesn't start so i'll try starting from Strech-lite soon.